# Uncaught TypeError: data.map is not a function in React.JS

Tags: reactjs, strapi

Uncaught TypeError: data.map is not a function in React.J i am getting this error i don't know whats wrong with the code please help.

```
{data && data.map((blog) => (
            <BlogLists key={blog.id} blog={blog.attributes} />
          ))}
```

```
data: Array(5)
0: {id: 1, attributes: {…}}
1: {id: 2, attributes: {…}}
2: {id: 3, attributes: {…}}
3: {id: 4, attributes: {…}}
4: {id: 5, attributes: {…}}
length: 5
```

Comment: How did you build the data array? maybe you are changing it somewhere.

Comment: Are you sure that the data you are logging to console and the data you are using in the JSX are point to same object?

Comment: @FaFa data array is coming from strapi backend and i did console.logged it.

Comment: @vighnesh153 yes i am sure that both data are the same as because there is no other data variable i am using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **Array.isArray(data)** to check the data type.
Probabbly the DOM might get the value as empty object which is causing the issue.